# Raises Object reference not set to an instance of an object - ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a web page and it displays a data entering form. Its first element is a `textbox` and it will ask to enter ID of mother. After entering the Id it will post to the server to search is mother exist or not. If exist it returns data to the view and displays them on the form. I coded it according to my logic as follows. But when I run the page it raises an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" from the `View.cshtml` page.

Controller.cs

```
public IActionResult Index(string id)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        SearchData(id); //This is asked to search mother
    }
    return View();
}

public void SearchData(string id)
{
    using (_context)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {                    
            var Mother = _context.Mothers.Where(p => p.NIC == id).ToList();                   
            if (Mother.Any())
            {                        
                ViewData["Mother"] = Mother;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
 @{ var m = ViewData["Mother"] as School_Mgt.Models.Students.Mother; }

 <input asp-for="NICM" name="NICM" placeholder="NIC No." type="text" value="@m.NIC">  
 <input asp-for="FNameM" name="FNameM" placeholder="Name in full" type="text" value="@m.FName">
  ...
```

Comment: What happens if `id` is empty? Check on your `View`: `if(ViewData["Mother"] !=null){//your logic here}`;

Comment: You should debug your controller and see what is returned as "Mother". Is it null? Is it of a different type?

Comment: ViewData["Mother"] is not empty. I checked. If you please see this screen capture. http://prntscr.com/rvhp42

Comment: After executing this code line  @{ var m = ViewData["Mother"] as School_Mgt.Models.Students.Mother; }  m is null which is not set to an object. Please see this screen capturehttp://prntscr.com/rvhvyl

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. By changing var Mother = _context.Mothers.Where(p => p.NIC == id).ToList(); to var Mother = _context.Mothers.Where(p => p.NIC == id).FirstOrDefault(); – chandrasiri just now   Edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ViewData["Mother"] = Mother; you are getting data in list of data
you can try

```
 var Mother = _context.Mothers.Where(p => p.NIC == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

if you are trying to work with single data else

```
   @{ var m = ViewData["Mother"] as IEnumerable<School_Mgt.Models.Students.Mother;>}
```

if you are trying to work with multiple data.

Comment: After executing this code line @{ var m = ViewData["Mother"] as School_Mgt.Models.Students.Mother; } m is null which is not set to an object. Please see this screen capturehttp://prntscr.com/rvhvyl –

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. By changing  var Mother = _context.Mothers.Where(p => p.NIC == id).ToList();  to 
var Mother = _context.Mothers.Where(p => p.NIC == id).FirstOrDefault();